# Symfony framework: Server returns error 500 to me, and I have no clue what is wrong

Tags: logging, symfony1

I am going through the Jobeet tutorial for symfony newbies. The server returns err 500 when I try and access `http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/job`.

As far as I can tell there is nowhere where I can read what the problem is in any log. And when I try and access `job`, symfony doesnt display a panel at the top to help me figure out what went wrong.

I must be missing something.

Thank you.

Kind regrads,
Marius

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug 500 Error in Symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577003/how-to-debug-500-error-in-symfony-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all those errors are written in the log file of php on your local wamp/lap server

or in the log folder in your symfony project root. there is a file frontend_dev.log...

EDIT: with that kind of description, nobody can tell what you are forgetting...