# How to debug 500 Error in Symfony 2 and above

Tags: symfony, xdebug

I am struggling with Symfony 2 error reporting because I can't find out what really is happing when a 500 Error is triggered.

I have XDebug correctly installed, but it seems like Symfony rules everything.

The custom pages just says:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

That's pretty much funny! Something is broken, but, the fact is that I need to fix my code, but can't know what or where it is the problem! And sure, If I send an email for the Symfony team will they be able to solve my problem once I not even know what to say them?

Some clue on what I am missing here?

Comment: In your url you should have `hostname/web/app_dev.php/....` , in order to see the explicit error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony assetic gives 500 error when requesting files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636025/symfony-assetic-gives-500-error-when-requesting-files)

Comment: Sometimes it happens after moving from dev to prod. In those cases, make sure to do a `bin/console cache:cl` and `rm -rf var/cache/*`. In my case there was no log errors anywhere, but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

##### For Symfony 2 and below,

First, look at the logs in `app/logs` depending on your environment — `dev.log` for development, `prod.log` for production, etc.

If the code crashes before Symfony has a chance to run, check the logs of your web server — e.g. nginx.

Comment: Also, make sure that the app/logs folder is writeable and has the right owner.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a symfony flex project, it is also possible that you forgot to install monolog ;) Run:

```
composer req log
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For Symfony versions 3.x, 4.x, 5.x, 6.x and above,

The logs will be found depending on the environment

- For **dev** env - `var/logs/dev.log`
- For **prod** env- `var/logs/prod.log`

---

Also, as the accepted answer suggests, you might have to check the server logs if your app crashes before even reaching Symfony.

Usual location for server logs is listed below -

- For **apache** server - `ls /var/log/apache2`
- For **Nginx** server - `ls /var/log/nginx`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod -R o+w var/cache/
```

from inside the project's folder,
solved the problem for me, at least this time :)

There were no errors in Symfony's or web server's logs.

### What caused the problem

It turned out that the problem was caused by me previously removing the cache folder, and regenerating the cache, i.e.

```
rm -fr var/cache/
./bin/console cache:clear
```

After that, `var/cache` became `drwxr-xr-x`.